# Scrapy Error: Couldn't bind: 24: Too many open files

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm running Scrapy on a list of domains, and a lot of the pages are getting this error:
`Couldn't bind: 24: Too many open files.`

I was not getting this error on my linux machine, but I am now getting it on my Mac. I'm not sure if this is to do with running on Sierra or if perhaps I left out a Scrapy configuration. I checked `ulimit` and it returns `unlimited` so I don't *think* it is that.

In case it is to do with my spider, here is that:

```
class JakeSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'jake'
    allowed_domains = allowedDomains
    start_urls = startUrls
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
    )


    def parse_page(self, response):
        page = response.url
        domain = urlparse(page).netloc
        domain = domain.replace('www.','')
        #print(domain, 'is domain and page is', page)
        linksToGet = getHotelUrlsForDomain(domain)
        #if(len(linksToGet) == 0):
        #    print('\n ... links to get was zero \n')
        #print('linksToGet = ', linksToGet)
        links = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            if link in linksToGet:
                print('\n\n\n   found one! ', link, 'is on', domain, ' and the page is', page,'\n\n\n')
                with open('hotelBacklinks.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
                    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                    writer.writerow({'hotelURL':link, 'targetDomain': domain})
```

Edit: here is the full error line for one of them. It isn't causing the scrape to crash, but there are a lot of lines like this, so I think I'm not getting as many pages as I otherwise would. The error line:
`2017-09-24 14:21:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://alabamatheatre.com/>: Couldn't bind: 24: Too many open files.`

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: You're making us guess _where_ the error is happening.  Edit your question to include the full error traceback, including the line of your code that causes the error.

Comment: Also, it would probably be better to open the csv file once at the top of your function, instead of closing and re-opening it for every link.

Comment: @JohnGordon, thank you, I've added in one of them. This is an error logged from Scrapy, and it isn't a critical error so I'm not getting a traceback with the specific line of my code that is causing it. Also, thanks for the csv tip, I've fixed that.

Answer (score -1):

1. You should use `pipeline` for saving all scraped data.
2. You have this error because you have many calls function `parse_page`. Every function tries to open and write to the same file. Write to file is block operation
   Here is doc from Scrapy https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html